# PingFederate: issuing an access token locally

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, pingfederate

Is it possible in PingFederate to issue an access token to the local user by his credentials without interacting any external clients or IdPs, so that the user will be authenticated by the server itself?

For example:
**Request**

```
POST localhost:8080/token.oauth2?username=user&password=pass
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==
```

**Response**

```
{
    "access_token": "0ed4ab08-c979-4f07-89fb-501a4ef2968f",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "f3fbccf0-0846-46c1-b3d9-cab41e714696",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "openid profile email"
}
```

Is there any authentication protocol that describes such a scenario? Not obviously derived from OAuth 2.0.

Comment: You're using OAuth as an example, but you don't want an answer using OAuth for the example? I'm not sure what you are asking for. There are a number of examples that I can give, but, I'd rather provide you with an answer rather than 20 examples.

Comment: I've documented options for realizing a scenario like that with PingFederate here: https://github.com/zandbelt/ping-scripts/blob/master/ropc-oidc.sh

Comment: @AndrewK., I'd prefer oauth-compliant examples, but I simply did not find anything reliable neither in Oauth2.0 nor in OpenId Connect docs.

Comment: Have you looked at Hans' script in his comment above? Solid example there.